# How to save textarea multiline text to Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, textarea, multiline

I have this `textArea` input field for `blogPost` text content that may contain multiline text, like:

```
This is paragraph one.
(empty line)
This is paragraph two.
```

I will display it (when loading the `blogPosts` in my App) inside a `<p>` tag with `white-space: pre-wrap;`

How should I save this to Cloud Firestore?

**What I've got so far:**

I'm thinking about saving as `JSON.stringify(textareaValue);`

How can I do this? Any better options?

Comment: any piece of code that you have already tried?

Comment: The one on the question: `JSON.stringify(textareaValue);`, but it turns every newLine to `\n` and I don't know if I should convert to `<br>` or not. I was hoping there was some best practice on how to do this. I've looked around but haven't found anything reliable. Thanks!

Comment: have you checked this docs? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart The information you are providing is really vague, it's hard to help you other than this

Comment: Yes. But they don't have a multiline example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Firestore will store exactly what you send it.  If you need the string to be something different at the time you render it on screen (like converting newlines to `<br>`), then you will have to make those modifications yourself.